# complex sql query to get data from four tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables as below

**table-1**

mysql> `select * from  PDB_PROFILE`                   ;

```
+-------+------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| PR_ID | PR_NAME                | PR_PARENTID | PR_TYPE           | PR_KEY                                                    |
+-------+------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1094 | suresh                 |        1077 | service           | serviceproviders::smstest::suresh                         |
```

**table-2**

mysql> select * from  MDB_PERMITTED_ADDRESS;

```
+---------+------------+
| ADDRESS | SERVICE_ID |
+---------+------------+
| 4444    |       1094 |
+---------+------------+
```

**table-3**

mysql> select * from  MDB_SERVICE_CONN_PR;

```
+-------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------+------------+---------------------+
| PR_ID | DRIVER_CONN_ID | ALLOCATION_TYPE | EXC_SERVICE_ID | EXT_ID | DEFAULT_OA | SC_ASSIGN_DATE      |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------+------------+---------------------+
|  1161 |           1158 | e               |           1094 |   NULL | NULL       | 2014-08-14 11:28:20 |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+--------+------------+---------------------+
```

**table-4**

mysql> select * from  MDB_DRIVER_CONN_PR;

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------+
| PR_ID | DRIVER_ID | PARENT_ID | TYPE | SHORT_NUMBER | DESCRIPTION | ID_TYPE | DEFAULT_OA | IS_GLOBAL | DEFAULT_SERVICE_ID | CONN_CATEGORY | SC_CREATION_DATE    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1158 |      1067 |      NULL | SMS  | 2222*        |             | s       | 2222       | n         |               NULL | Generic       | 2014-08-14 11:28:07 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+--------------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

check the first table where PR_TYPE=service then need to take PR_ID for the same and get data from other three tables wrt PR_ID

finally i require output as below

```
+------------------------+------------+---------+
| PR_NAME                | DEFAULT_OA | ADDRESS |
+------------------------+------------+---------+
| suresh                 | 2222       | 4444    |
+------------------------+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is correct

```
SELECT  P.PR_NAME,
        DC.DEFAULT_OA,
        PA.ADDRESS 
FROM    PDB_PROFILE P
JOIN    MDB_PERMITTED_ADDRESS PA ON P.PR_ID = PA.SERVICE_ID
JOIN    MDB_SERVICE_CONN_PR SC ON P.PR_ID = SC.EXC_SERVICE_ID
JOIN    MDB_DRIVER_CONN_PR DC ON SC.DRIVER_CONN_ID = DC.PR_ID
```

Comment: thanks, i am getting exact output
mysql> SELECT  P.PR_NAME,
    ->         DC.DEFAULT_OA,
    ->         PA.ADDRESS 
    -> FROM    PDB_PROFILE P
    -> JOIN    MDB_PERMITTED_ADDRESS PA ON P.PR_ID = PA.SERVICE_ID
    -> JOIN    MDB_SERVICE_CONN_PR SC ON P.PR_ID = SC.EXC_SERVICE_ID
    -> JOIN    MDB_DRIVER_CONN_PR DC ON SC.DRIVER_CONN_ID = DC.PR_ID;
+---------+------------+---------+
| PR_NAME | DEFAULT_OA | ADDRESS |
+---------+------------+---------+
| suresh  | 2222       | 4444    |
+---------+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

Answer (score 0):

This query should help you!

```
select TAB1.PR_NAME , TAB4.DEFAULT_OA,  TAB2.ADDRESS 
from  PDB_PROFILE TAB1, 
      MDB_PERMITTED_ADDRESS TAB2,
      MDB_SERVICE_CONN_PR TAB3, 
      MDB_DRIVER_CONN_PR TAB4

WHERE TAB1.PR_ID = TAB2.SERVICE_ID
AND TAB1.PR_ID = TAB3.EXC_SERVICE_ID
AND TAB3.DRIVER_CONN_ID = TAB4.PR_ID
AND TAB1.PR_TYPE = 'service'
```